# How to fix the "handle" clause on my code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

When I trying to declared the button on handles clause, it gives me an error.

```
Public Class frmVRHeadsest
    Private picCrown As Object
    Private picEarbud As Object
    Private btnExit As Object

    Private Sub BtnCrown_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles *btnCrown*.Click

        picCrown.Visible = True
        picEarbud.Visible = False
        btnExit.Enable = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnEarbud_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles *btnEarbud*.Click
        picEarbud.Visible = True
        picCrown.Visible = False
        btnExit.Enable = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object E As EventArgs) Handles *btnExit*.Click

        FileClose()

    End Sub

End Class
```

I got an error and now I can't see my design in visual basic

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare those variables as [WithEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/withevents), and change from `Object` to whatever they actually are (`PictureBox`/`Button`?).

Change:

```
Private picCrown As Object
Private picEarbud As Object
Private btnExit As Object
```

To:

```
Private WithEvents picCrown As PictureBox
Private WithEvents picEarbud As PictureBox
Private WithEvents btnExit As Button
```

But that doesn't take care of the CREATION and setup of those controls. Are you instantiating and initializing them somewhere else?...